# How can I handle TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

**Usually** TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) occurs.

But **rarely** scraping script get exact data from website.

This is snippet code I've written.

```
Netbet = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("/usr/bin/chromedriver"))
Netbet.get("https://www.livepartners.com/")
Netbet.implicitly_wait(10)
Netbet.find_element_by_id("login_username").send_keys("username")
Netbet.find_element_by_id("login_password").send_keys("password")
pwd = Netbet.find_element_by_id("login_password")
pwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
waiter = wait(Netbet, 10)
waiter.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="contentwrapper"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div')))
balance = Netbet.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contentwrapper"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/strong').text
```

With this script, I can scrape exact data **rarely**, but **usually** get `TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)` error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "netbet.py", line 43, in <module>
        data = netbet_scrapping()
    File "netbet.py", line 31, in netbet_scrapping
        waiter.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="contentwrapper"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div')))
    File "/home/elite/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
        raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout in waiter = wait(netbet, 10) to a larger number to see whether that reduces your timeouts? You can put a try/except block around `waiter.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(...))` to explicitly handle timeout exceptions more gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you tell me more detail?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java selenium timeout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513338/java-selenium-timeout-page)

Comment: @KyanHeuvel While you access `https://www.livepartners.com/` first you need to click on `Login / Register` button then only you will be able to provide `username` and `password` through `send_keys` method, Thanks.